# How to find the limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this limit: $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}.$$
I think I know how to solve it using L'Hôpital's rule (please correct me if this is wrong):
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{8x^7+4+2^x\cdot \ln{2}}{2^x\cdot  \ln{2} +6x^5}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{56x^6+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^2}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^2 +30x^4}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{336x^5+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^3}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^3 +160x^3}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1680x^4+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^4}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^4 +480x^2}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{6720x^3+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^5}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^5 +960x}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{20160x^2+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^6}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^6 +960}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{40320x+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^7}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^7}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{40320+2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^8}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^8}=
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^9}{2^x\cdot (\ln{2})^9}=1.$$
This seems overly complicated though. I think an easier way would be to factor out the "dominating" term. I'm a bit new to that so I would appreciate some guidance. $x^8$ grows faster than $2^x$ when $x$ is small. But in this limit, $x$ is approaching $\infty$. I'm not sure, but I think $2^x$ will have passed $x^8$ at that point. Does that mean I should factor out $2^x$ and if so how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $2^{x}$ is the dominating term. Divide all the terms by $2^{x}$ and take the limit for each term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}& = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}\\& = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x(x^7+4)+2^x}{(x^6 +1) + 2^x}\\& = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{x(x^7+4)}{2^x}+1}{\frac{(x^6 +1)}{2^x} + 1}\tag{$*$}\\& = \frac{0 + 1}{0 + 1}\\& = 1\end{align}

> $(*)$ Exponential functions grow much faster than the polynomials. Therefore the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(x^7+4)}{2^x}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^6 + 1}{2^x}$ will tend to $0$. You may also apply L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate both of these limits.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use L'Hopital's rule; the fastest method is using asymptotic behaviour. Since the exponential grows faster that any polynomial, you have:
$$\frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}\sim\frac{2^x}{2^x}=1 $$
Hence
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^8+4x+2^x}{2^x+x^6+1}=1 $$

Answer (score 0):

At infinity, 2^x grows much faster than x^8, so you can indeed factor everything by 2^x and we get your result.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}x^k2^{-x}=0$ which is a key part of all the answers, we can use elementary methods. First of all substituting $x=ky $ gives $$(ky)^k2^{-ky}=k^k(y2^{-y})^k$$ Therefore we have reduced the task to $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to \infty}y2^{-y}.$ Assume $3\le n\le y<n+1.$ Then $$y2^{-y}\le (n+1)2^{-n}\le 2n\,2^{-n}$$ We have $2^n>{n\choose 2}={1\over 2}n(n-1).$ Hence $$0\le y2^{-y}\le {4\over n-1}\le {4\over y-2}$$ which implies that the limit is equal $0.$